# Cannot execute Bash script from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html, bash, sudo

I'm trying to execute a simple `Bash Script` from `PHP` script. I collect data from a `HTML5` front end page, pass through `ajax` to the PHP script, take the variables and then, pass these to the `.sh` script, but I've got messages like:

```
./test_bash.sh: line 13: ./test.txt: Permission denied
```

I tried to change the permissions `chmod 777 test_bash.sh`, tried to modify the `sudoers.d` file, tried this: `shell_exec("echo password_for_the_user | sudo -S command_to_execute");` ... but the `Bash script` can't write the `test.txt` file.

Here is my basic code, first the `PHP code`:

```
<?php 
$var1 = json_decode($_POST['var1']); //from front-end html5
$var2 = json_decode($_POST['var2']);
$var3 = json_decode($_POST['var3']);

$response = shell_exec("./test_bash.sh $var1 $var2 $var3 2>&1");

echo "$response";
?>
```

Secondly, the `Bash` code:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$1;
var2=$2;
var3=$3;

echo "$var1";
echo "$var2";
echo "$var3";

echo $var1 $var2 $var3 > ./test.txt
```

Comment: Does it work if you say `echo $var1 $var2 $var3 > /tmp/test.txt`? It looks like you cannot write in the dir where `test.txt` is.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to change the permissions on the txt file also in order for apache ( the user that is actually executing the script ) to be able to write to it.

Be careful though when using `shell_exec()` and changing permissions it is quite easy to pass unwanted variables...

Comment: be careful though for `$var='hello; rm -rf .'` or something similar @Sergi

Answer (score 1):

When you are saying

```
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 > ./test.txt
```

You are `echo`ing var1, var2 and var3 into the file `test.txt` that lies in the same directory as the script that is running it.

So if you are in `/var/www`, doing `echo $var1 $var2 $var3 > ./test.txt` will be the same as saying `echo $var1 $var2 $var3 > /var/www/test.txt`.

The problem you are facing consists in this error:

> ./test_bash.sh: line 13: ./test.txt: Permission denied

This is telling you that you are not allowed to write into the file `/var/www/test.txt`. To be able to do so, change the write permissions to this file so that "others" (that is, user `www` or `apache`) can write into it:

```
chmod o+w /var/www/test.txt
```

Or, probably better, write into another directory. For example `/tmp`.

Finally, note that [it is recommendable to quote your vars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/1983854). So better say:

```
echo "$var1 $var2 $var3" > test.txt
#    ^                 ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying @fedorqui ! It helps too!